# Working with two different baseUrl - AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am using AFHTTPSessionManager to make api calls on the web. I have signleton object of session manager and it initiates the base url once. Occasionally, I am in a need of making api call with different baseurl. And its readonly in AFNetworking.h file.

What is the proper way of handing different baseurl here? Plese help.

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedClient {

    static ApiClient *_sharedClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kTraktBaseURLString]];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}
```

Comment: I generally use absolute URLs for this, in which case the baseURL is ignored

Comment: did u found any solution to this?

Comment: No not yet. I use two different classes.

Comment: I too wish there was a way to change the baseUrl.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the behaviour of `+URLWithString:relativeToURL:` method to override baseURL.

Matt [mentioned it in Docs](http://marker.to/4iSBxe)

> For HTTP convenience methods, the request serializer constructs URLs from the path relative to the baseURL, using NSURL +URLWithString:relativeToURL:, when provided. If baseURL is nil, path needs to resolve to a valid NSURL object using NSURL +URLWithString:.
>
> Below are a few examples of how baseURL and relative paths interact:
>
> ```
> NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/v1/"];
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                  //  http://example.com/v1/foo
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"foo?bar=baz" relativeToURL:baseURL];          // http://example.com/v1/foo?bar=baz
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/foo
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                 // http://example.com/v1/foo
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"/foo/" relativeToURL:baseURL];                // http://example.com/foo/
> [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example2.com/" relativeToURL:baseURL]; // http://example2.com/
> ```

So if you want to alter baseURL for single request, you can pass Absolute URL as a `URLString` argument to `GET:parameters:success:failure:` instead of URL path.

```
[manager GET:@"http://otherBaseURL.com/url/path" parameters:nil success:... failure:...]
```