# Change Base URL of AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios8, singleton, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have created a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` with a singleton (code below) but now I need to adjust the Base URL based on the users location (to call a different server in a different part of the world based on the users location). It seems like most examples of this class use a singleton which does not allow you to adjust the base URL (read only property). Is there an easy way for me to adjust the base URL using `AFHTTPSessionManager`?

```
 + (RebelBaseManager *)sharedRebelBaseHTTPClient; {

static RebelBaseManager *_sharedRebelBaseHTTPManager = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    _sharedRebelBaseHTTPManager = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL];
    _sharedRebelBaseHTTPManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates =YES;
});
return _sharedRebelBaseHTTPManager;

}
```

Comment: Shared mutable state is a bad idea. The `baseURL` property is `readonly` for this reason. Instead, you should be creating instances with different `baseURL`s as necessary—or perhaps even opting out of that functionality entirely.

Comment: @mattt I was afraid of that :)... I appreciate the response.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32124978/991816) is a bit related if you decide to compose absolute URLs manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested here is the method I created that I call whenever I need to adjust the Base URL for a call using `AFHTTPSessionManager`

```
- (AFHTTPSessionManager *) createNewSessionManager {

//Load User Defaults
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//Create url based on user location
AFHTTPSessionManager *newDataCall = nil;
if (![userDefaults valueForKey:@"baseURL"]) {
    [userDefaults setObject:@"https://BASE-URL" forKey:@"baseURL"];
}
newDataCall = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDefaults valueForKey:@"baseURL"]]];
newDataCall.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates =YES;
newDataCall.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
newDataCall.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

return newDataCall;
}
```

Comment: i feel this will end up in creating new sessionManager object. As soon as we change the url we need to call initWithBaseURL function for new base url right

Comment: Yes. So before I call this method I look at where the user is (in terms of location) what base url I am calling and then if I need to call a different base url (to call a server in a different part of the world) I call this method. I store the url I should be calling in user defaults which you can see in the method above.